# SQL REPLACE DIGIT

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2008, substring, regexp-replace

How to replace in SQL any digit followed by ) with an empty string

for example 'Hi my name is M and I have two sister 1) M and 2) K'

I want to convert it to 'Hi my name is M and I have two sister  M and  K'

I don't want to repeat replace for all digits

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
UPDATE example_table set example_column = REGEXP_REPLACE(example_column,'[0-9)]+','')
```

For a better result

```
'[0-9]+[)]'
or
'[0-9]+[)]+' //  ... * there is no limit
```

You also can simply run

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Hi my name is M and I have two sister 1) M and 2) K','[0-9]+[)]','')
```

or you can use where clause to customize more